# Problema com condição em query SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma query que busca informações de duas tabelas diferentes, com duas condições. Aparentemente ela funcionava bem, porém quando o campo `a.vendedor` está vazio, o resultado é nulo.

Eu entendo que o resultado tinha que ser esse mesmo, porém gostaria de saber se eu consigo (alterando a query) retornar as outras linhas do *SELECT*, excluindo o `b.nome` quando `a.vendedor=b.codigo` for falso.

Eu já tentei usar o `OR` ao invés do `AND`, mas o resultado não é o esperado.

Resultado normal:

```
[
  {
    descricao: "1",
    cliente: "José Paulo Rodrigues",
    local: "Mesa 1",
    nome: "Armando Azevedo"
  }
]
```

Resultado "esperado" quando `a.vendedor` é vazio (quando `a.vendedor = b.codigo` não for verdade):

```
[
  {
    descricao: "1",
    cliente: "José Paulo Rodrigues",
    local: "Mesa 1",
    nome: "0"
  }
]
```

Meu código:

```
$codigo = $_GET['cod'];
$sqlcode = mysql_query("SELECT a.descricao, a.cliente, a.local, b.nome 
                        FROM terminal_cartao a, funcionarionew b 
                        WHERE descricao='$codigo' AND a.vendedor=b.codigo");

while($result=mysql_fetch_object($sqlcode))
{
  $jsonObj[] = $result;
}

$final_res = json_encode($jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisará utilizar um `LEFT JOIN` em sua query:

```
SELECT a.descricao, a.cliente, a.local, b.nome 
FROM terminal_cartao a
LEFT JOIN funcionarionew b ON a.vendedor = b.codigo
WHERE descricao='$codigo';
```

Mais informações sobre joins nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/4751).

Outra coisa: evite usar `mysql_*` em seu código: essas [funções já foram descontinuadas](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Procure utilizar [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) para acessar o banco de dados ao invés de `mysql_*`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, isso funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @ReneSá considere abandonar o quanto antes mysql_ para acesso ao banco de dados.

Comment: [Algo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql) que possa vir a ajudar sobre `mysqli_`